# Is there any way to trigger scheduled task in a sequence?

Tags: wso2, scheduled-tasks, sequence, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a scheduled task which performs an operation in 40min periods. But, I want to trigger this task in a Sequence when the HTTP response code is 401 for example. Is there any way to do this?

WSO2 version 6.4.0

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, a scheduled task is just that. A task that runs on a schedule. However, generally the task will be used to send a message to a sequence/proxy/api to start that.

So possibly you can do just that when your other sequence receives the 401 response, call whatever it is that is normally triggered by your scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

> which performs an operation

What kind of operation?

You may put this operation in a special sequence.
And call this sequence from scheduled task and from your second sequence in case of HTTP error 401.

```
<filter source="$axis2:HTTP_SC" regex="401">
<then>
    <sequence key="my_first_sequence"/>
<then>
</filter>
```